# Mac OS : systemwide environment variables

Tags: macos, environment-variables

I am having my system wide environment variables in file `/Users/kuldeep/.MacOSX/environment.plist` and it was working fine. I am not sure what exactly got changed these are no more picked from the file. Is there any other way to set the variables system wide so that they can also be loaded by java as well.

My plist file looks like below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>AWS_ACCESS_KEY</key>
        <string>loremipsum</string>
        <key>AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID</key>
        <string>loremipsum</string>
        <key>AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY</key>
        <string>loremipsumloremipsum</string>
        <key>AWS_SECRET_KEY</key>
        <string>loremipsumloremipsum</string>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

What could be done differently.

Comment: How was it working? Who/what was parsing/processing it? How is it system-wide if it's in your personal user directory? Did you upgrade your macOS?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I used this GUI tool which updates the `.MacOSX/environment.plist` and updates environment. 
Tool:  https://github.com/hschmidt/EnvPane

Comment: no, I did not upgrade my OS.